# Bootstrap : <h4> title not on a new line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following HTML code using Bootstrap 3 CSS classes :

```
<h4>Profile</h4>
<div class="row form-group col-sm-8">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name :</label>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    myName
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row form-group col-sm-8">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email :</label>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    me@internet.org
  </div>
</div>

<h4>Credits</h4>
<div class="form-group col-sm-8">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Credits :</label>
  <div class="col-sm-7">
    42
  </div>
</div>
```

I'd like the `Credits` `<h4>` title to be on a new line, under the previous fields. But it's displayed on the top right.

Can someone please explain me why and help me display it to the right position ?

CSS Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't look anything like the code you've provided in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `col-` classes make the elements they are applied to floats. You will need to wrap them in a container with `clearfix`. You probably want this (note that `row` applies clearfix too):

```
<h4>Profile</h4>
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-8">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name :</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        myName
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-8">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email :</label>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        me@internet.org
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<h4>Credits</h4>
<div class="form-group col-sm-8">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Credits :</label>
  <div class="col-sm-7">
    42
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new div with the class 'row' for the credits:

```
<div class="row">
    <h4>Credits</h4>
</div>
```